# How to pass data from database to multiples tables on one file with TCPDF?

Tags: php, database, html-table, output, tcpdf

I am trying to create a PDF with the data from my database. I divide my data to be displayed with many tables like shown below. I tried to fetch the data from my database with the $output and fetch data.

How can I do for each data to display below the corresponding  that are in my tables with the same name?

Because i have different tables, should I do multiple function to fetch my data from database with each function for each table?

```php
$session_id ="0";
 function fetch_data()  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "thermoform_data");  
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM form_data WHERE id = '1' ORDER BY id ASC";  
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {       
      $output .= '<tr>
                    <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["session_id"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["manufacturing_name"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["head_office"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["legal_form"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["activity"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["filiales"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["products"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["website"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["telephone"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["fax"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["email"].'</td>

                    <td>'.$row["project_name"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["first_last_name_manager"].'</td>

                    <td>'.$row["title_manager"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["tel_manager"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["email_manager"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["country_manager"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["zip_code_manager"].'</td>
                 <td>'.$row["first_last_name_collaborator1"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["title_collaborator1"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["tel_collaborator1"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["email_collaborator1"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["country_collaborator1"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["zip_code_collaborator1"].'</td>
                 <td>'.$row["first_last_name_collaborator2"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["title_collaborator2"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["tel_collaborator2"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["email_collaborator2"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["country_collaborator2"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["zip_code_collaborator2"].'</td>

                    <td>'.$row["project_charter"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["project_management_plan"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["project_scope_plan"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["project_schedule_plan"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["project_risk_plan"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["project_work_plan"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["project_team_plan"].'</td>

                    <td>'.$row["material_type"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["manufacturer"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["trade_name"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["physical_properties"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["chemical_properties"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["alloy_composition"].'</td>

                    <td>'.$row["technology_solutions"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["reporting_and_dashboards"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["data_analysis"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["software_consulting"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["system_analysis"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["training"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["accounting_services"].'</td>
                </tr>
                          ';  
      }  
      return $output;  
 }  
 if(isset($_POST["generate_pdf"]))  
 {  
      require_once('TCPDF-master/tcpdf.php');  
      $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);  
      $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);  
      $obj_pdf->SetTitle("Form data");  
      $obj_pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);  
      $obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));  
      $obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
      $obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');  
      $obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);  
      /*$obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '0', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);  */
      $obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
      $obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);  
      $obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);  
      $obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 9);  
      $obj_pdf->AddPage('L'); 

      $content = '';  
      $content .= '  
      <h4 align="center">Form data</h4><br /> 
      <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">  
           <tr>  
                <th>Id</th>  
                <th>session_id</th>  
                <th>manufacturing_name</th>  
                <th>head_office</th> 
                <th>legal_form</th> 
                <th>activity</th> 
                <th>filiales</th> 
                <th>products</th> 
                <th>website</th> 
                <th>telephone</th> 
                <th>fax</th>
                <th>email</th>

                <th>project_name</th> 
                <th>first_last_name_manager</th> 
                <th>title_manager</th> 
                <th>tel_manager</th> 
                <th>email_manager</th> 
                <th>country_manager</th> 
                <th>zip_code_manager</th> 
                <th>first_last_name_collaborator1</th> 
                <th>title_collaborator1</th> 
                <th>tel_collaborator1</th> 
                <th>email_collaborator1</th> 
                <th>country_collaborator1</th> 
                <th>zip_code_collaborator1</th> 
                <th>first_last_name_collaborator2</th> 
                <th>title_collaborator2</th> 
                <th>tel_collaborator2</th> 
                <th>email_collaborator2</th> 
                <th>country_collaborator2</th> 
                <th>zip_code_collaborator2</th> 

                <th>project_charter</th> 
                <th>project_management_plan</th> 
                <th>project_scope_plan</th>
                <th>project_schedule_plan</th> 
                <th>project_risk_plan</th> 
                <th>project_work_plan</th> 
                <th>project_team_plan</th>

                <th>material_type</th> 
                <th>manufacturer</th> 
                <th>trade_name</th> 
                <th>physical_properties</th> 
                <th>chemical_properties</th> 
                <th>alloy_composition</th>

                <th>technology_solutions</th> 
                <th>reporting_and_dashboards</th> 
                <th>data_analysis</th> 
                <th>software_consulting</th> 
                <th>system_analysis</th> 
                <th>training</th> 
                <th>accounting_services</th> 

           </tr> 

      '; 

$tbl1 = '';
$tbl1 .= '
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" nobr="true">
 <tr>
  <th colspan="11" align="center">NON-BREAKING TABLE</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Id</td>
  <td>session_id</td>
  <td>manufacturing_name</td>
  <td>head_office</td>
  <td>legal_form</td>
  <td>activity</td>
  <td>filiales</td>
  <td>products</td>
  <td>websites</td>
  <td>fax</td>
  <td>email</td>
 </tr>

</table>
';

$obj_pdf->writeHTML($tbl1, true, false, false, false, '');

     $tbl2="";
    $tbl2 .= '
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" nobr="true">
 <tr>
  <th colspan="7" align="center">NON-BREAKING TABLE</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>project_name</td>
  <td>first_last_name_manager</td>
  <td>title_manager</td>
  <td>tel_manager</td>
  <td>email_manager</td>
  <td>country_manager</td>
  <td>zip_code_manager</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>first_last_name_collaborator1</td>
  <td>title_collaborator1</td>
  <td>tel_collaborator1</td>
  <td>email_collaborator1</td>
  <td>country_collaborator1</td>
  <td>zip_code_collaborator1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>first_last_name_collaborator2</td>
  <td>title_collaborator2</td>
  <td>tel_collaborator2</td>
  <td>email_collaborator2</td>
  <td>country_collaborator2</td>
  <td>zip_code_collaborator2</td>
 </tr>

</table>
';

$obj_pdf->writeHTML($tbl2, true, false, false, false, '');

     $tbl3="";
     $tbl3 .='
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" nobr="true">
 <tr>
  <th colspan="7" align="center">NON-BREAKING TABLE</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>project_charter</td>
  <td>project_management_plan</td>
  <td>project_scope_plan</td>
  <td>pproject_schedule_plan</td>
  <td>project_risk_plan</td>
  <td>project_work_plan</td>
  <td>project_team_plan</td>
 </tr>

</table>
';

$obj_pdf->writeHTML($tbl3, true, false, false, false, '');

     $tbl4="";
     $tbl4 .='
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" nobr="true">
 <tr>
  <th colspan="6" align="center">NON-BREAKING TABLE</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>material_type</td>
  <td>manufacturer</td>
  <td>trade_name</td>
  <td>physical_properties</td>
  <td>chemical_properties</td>
  <td>alloy_composition</td>
 </tr>

</table>
';

$obj_pdf->writeHTML($tbl4);

     $tbl5="";
     $tbl5 ='
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" nobr="true">
 <tr>
  <th colspan="6" align="center">NON-BREAKING TABLE</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>technology_solutions</td>
  <td>reporting_and_dashboards</td>
  <td>data_analysis</td>
  <td>software_consulting</td>
  <td>system_analysis</td>
  <td>training</td>
  <td>accounting_services</td>
 </tr>

</table>
';

$obj_pdf->writeHTML($tbl5, true, false, false, false, '');


// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------



    /* header('Content-type: application/pdf');*/
     ob_get_clean();
     $obj_pdf->setAutoPageBreak(true, 0);
      $content .= fetch_data();  
      $content .= '</table>';  
      $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content); 
      $obj_pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'I');  
 }  
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>SoftAOX | Generate HTML Table Data To PDF From MySQL Database Using TCPDF In PHP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <br />
    <div class="container">
        <h4 align="center"> Generate HTML Table Data To PDF From MySQL Database Using TCPDF In PHP</h4><br />
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <div class="col-md-12" align="right">
                <form method="post" action="{{URL('index3')}}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <!-- <input type="number" name="session_id">-->
                    <input type="submit" name="generate_pdf" class="btn btn-success" value="Generate PDF" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th width="5%">Id</th>
                    <th width="30%">Name</th>
                    <th width="15%">Age</th>
                    <th width="50%">Email</th>
                </tr>
                <?php  
                     echo fetch_data();  
                     ?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Right now, none of my data are showing, I only have the row and my table but no data from database inside. I expected to see the data below each rows of my table with the corresponding names.

Comment: You are greatly over-complicating things. This can be solved with `$header=array_keys($row)` and a foreach statement to generate headers for column. Then simply do `foreach($row as $val) echo "<td>$val</td>"` (note: you will need to do extra stuff to escape html and whatnot). You can also write a simple script that will convert your DB names into reasonable ones by replacing underscores with spaces and capitalizing each first letter.

Comment: Hi thanks you! could you show me an exemple with my code please? im new to tcpdf and im visual. i would really appreciate it!

Comment: I found a way to do it Thanks you!